# poor prediction performance from (WEKA) classifiers

Tags: classification, model-evaluation

I have an imbalanced 2-class data set made of two parts - model creation data and prediction data. Model creation data is split into train and test data. Model is trained using the training data and tested on the test data, as usual. I do this several times to make sure that the data space is covered fully. The accuracy I get on each of the test data from the model based on the corresponding train data (produced by the cross validation procedure) is quite satisfactory.

However, when I apply any of these models to the prediction data the model prediction performance I get is rather poor. I am unsure as to what is going on. The statistical profile of the prediction data is similar to the training/test data and I expect to get similar prediction accuracy. One difference between the train and prediction data is that they are from different, but contiguous, time periods but there no time-related variables in the model.

How do I solve this problem? Any help from the community is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that your model has fall into overfitting. How many observations do you have and what is the number of independent variables in the model? What algorithm have you used to obtaine the model? To fight overfitting you may introduce regularization or use ensemble of weak classifiers (like random forest).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you can expand on your comment on regularization, that would be great. I am not sure if there is much over-fitting. The randomized cross-validation to select train and test data should help reduce over-fitting. As to the classifiers attempted, I have tried a whole bunch of models including random forest, logistic model tree, naive bayes tree, etc. NBTree has the best performance so far. There are 11 attributes + 1 binary class variable. The independent variables are a mix of categorical and numeric variables. Model data has 27000 and prediction data has 5700 records.

Comment: You can read about regularization elsewhere (Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics) for example). This discussion (http://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2011-December/054323.html) about regularization in WEKA also may help. However, with 27000 records and 11 variables it is hard to overfit (unless there is significant disproportion in classes). And I have no glue what may be another reason. Maybe time has significant influence. If it is possible, try to include time among your attributes and check the predictive power.